# Cannot read property of lat undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have seriously no idea why is this showing up.

This is my google map script tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

As you can see below i have defined the latitude as lat(). It's pointing the error at line 120 which is at distanceInMeters

```
  openMapPage()
  { 

    // GETTING THE CURRENT USER ADDRESS FOR LATITUDE AND LONGTITUDE
    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("request/" + uid);
    ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => { // <------ Here!
        var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
        var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
        var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();
        var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
        var requestsValue = snapshot.val();


       ref.once('value', (request) => {
  var currentUserAddress = request.val().regdetails.address;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': currentUserAddress}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      var latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      var meterLimit  = latlng;
      //var userAddress = new LatLng(currentUserAddress);
      console.log("SURESH IS COOL");
      console.log(meterLimit);

    } 
  }); 

});           

//END OF CURRENT USER 
}); 


  // GETTING THE ALL  USER ADDRESS FOR LATITUDE AND LONGTITUDE
    var ref1 = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref1.once("value").then((snapshot1) => { // <------ Here!
        var a = snapshot1.exists();  // true
        var c = snapshot1.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
        var d = snapshot1.child('reqdetails').exists();
        var requestsKey = snapshot1.key;
        var requestsValue = snapshot1.val();


        snapshot1.forEach((childSnapshot) => { // <------ And here!
            var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();
            var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;
            var AllUserAddress = requestValue.regdetails.address;

            //console.log("ALL USER ADDRESS");
            //console.log(AllUserAddress);

        var geocoder1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder1.geocode( { 'address': AllUserAddress}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude1 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude1 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      var latlng1 = new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
      //var userAddress = new LatLng(currentUserAddress);
      //console.log("SURESH IS COOL");
      //console.log(latlng1);
      var distanceInMeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (this.latlng, this.latlng1);
      console.log("DISTANCE");
      console.log(distanceInMeters);


    } 
  }); 



        });

    });







  }
```

The error looks something like this, It's keep saying lat. And my code has no error. Btw the error line 120 has no error though.
[image]

I can still console log all my user address lat and lng

[image]

Comment: can you provide you r whole code?

Comment: Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: looks like `location` is undefined.. can you log `results[0].geometry.location`?

Comment: Yup i can get all the lat and lng of all the user address.

Comment: maybe you are accessing incorrectly? can you share the output in the question?

Comment: See my updated post. I realized that if i remove line 120. i can console.log all the user lat and lng. But i need line 120 to compare.

Comment: is location an array? cant tell from the log though.you could debug a bit

Comment: the error is saying undefined lat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the case is that you haven't defined `this.latlng, this.latlng1` in your global scope, so you can't access them, you're trying to access local variables declared inside your functions that's why you can't get `distanceInMeters`. So try this:

```
public latlng; // DECLARE THEM ABOVE THE CONSTRUCTOR OF YOUR CLASS
public latlng1;

constructor(){
}

/* 
  DO THE FOLLOWING TO BOTH YOUR GEOCODERS:
  - GET BOTH LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE OF YOUR.
  - ACCESS YOUR GLOBAL latlng WITH this.
*/
geocoder1.geocode( { 'address': AllUserAddress}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    let latitude1 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    let longitude1 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    this.latlng1 = new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
    let distanceInMeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (this.latlng, this.latlng1);
    console.log("DISTANCE");
    console.log(distanceInMeters);
  } 
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much